Does not calculate normalization expressions, basic modes, sympy
I'm trying to calculate normalization expressions for poloidal velocity modes
from sympy import sqrt, integrate, symbols, diff
C1_, C2_, C3_, C4_, r,  z = symbols("C1_, C2_, C3_, C4_, r, z", real=True)
r_i = symbols('r_i', positive=True, real=True)
mu_ = symbols('mu_', positive=True, real=True)
N = 1
for n in range(1, N+1):
    j[n] = jn(n, z)
    y[n] = yn(n, z)
for n in range(1, N+1):
    RP_ = ((C1_ * j[n].subs(z, sqrt(mu_) * r)
           + C2_ * y[n].subs(z, sqrt(mu_) * r) + C3_ * r ** n + C4_ * r ** (-n-1)))
    Usymbol  = (n ** 2 * (n + 1) ** 2 * integrate(RP_ ** 2, (r, r_i, 1))
                  + integrate(diff(RP_, r) + RP_ / r, (r, r_i, 1)) ** 2 * r ** 2)

He doesn't count.
I tried it like this:
for n in range(1, N+1):
    RP_ = simplify((C1_ * j[n].subs(z, sqrt(mu_) * r)
           + C2_ * y[n].subs(z, sqrt(mu_) * r) + C3_ * r ** n + C4_ * r ** (-n-1)))
    Usymbol1 = n ** 2 * (n + 1) ** 2 * integrate(RP_ ** 2, (r, r_i, 1))
    RP_2 = simplify((diff(RP_, r) + RP_ / r) ** 2 * r ** 2)
    Usymbol2 = simplify(n * (n + 1) * integrate(RP_2, (r, r_i, 1)))
    Usymbol = Usymbol1 + Usymbol2

It doesn't help.
The same is true for poloidal magnetic modes.
for n in range(1, N+1):
    Usymbol = (n**2*(n+1)**2 * integrate((j[n].subs(z, sqrt(eta_)*r))**2, (r,0,1)) 
               + n*(n+1)*integrate(r**2 * (diff(j[n].subs(z, sqrt(eta_)*r),r) 
                                           + j[n].subs(z,sqrt(eta_))/r)**2, (r,0,1)))

I also tried to simplify it, but to no avail.
Sympy copes with integrals for toroidal modes.

Either use ru.stackoverflow.com or post a new question in English. You won't get any answers if people can't even read the question
